# List comprehension takes too much memory

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, lazy-evaluation

I'm a beginner to Haskell and used it to solve some 50 problems of [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) but now I'm stuck at [problem 66](http://projecteuler.net/problem=66). The problem is that the compiled code (`ghc -O2 --make problem66.hs`) takes all my machine's free memory after 10-20 seconds. My code looks like this:

```
-- Project Euler, problem 66

diophantine x y d = x^2 - d*y^2 == 1

minimalsolution d = take 1 [(x, y, d) | y <- [2..],
                            let x = round $ sqrt $ fromIntegral (d*y^2+1),
                            diophantine x y d]

issquare x = (round $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x)^2 == x

main = do
    print (map minimalsolution (filter (not . issquare) [1..1000]))
```

I have a hunch that the problem lies in the infinite list inside the list comprehension for `minimalsolution`.

I actually thought that due to lazyness, Haskell would evaluate the list only until it finds one element (because of `take 1`) and on the way discard everything for which `diophantine` evaluates to `False`. Am I wrong there?

Interestingly, I did not see this behaviour in ghci. Is it because processing inside ghci is so much slower that I just would have to wait until I see the memory consumption explode - or is it something else?

**No spoilers, please. All I want to know is where the extreme memory consumption comes from and how I can fix it.**

Comment: Does the list you're taking one from in `minimalsolution` always have an element?

Comment: It should have if the parameter `d` is non-square which is provided by the `filter` inside `main`. However it could well be that my algorithm is totally wrong. Note that sometimes it takes a while to find the actual solution because the numbers get huge quickly.

Comment: Depending on what ghc version you have you sometimes can get a nice surprise by using ghc -threaded option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it is worth I have tested this now after 6 years and this problem does not appear anymore. The memory consumption stays very low with GHC 8.6.5. I assume that this was indeed a problem in the compiler which has been fixed at some point.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't profiled before, so stone throwers are welcome.

Haskell determines that [2..] is a constant and is reused for every element of the list, despite take 1 using only one element of that list; so it memoizes the list for computing future elements of the same list. You get stuck computing value for d=61.

---

Edit:

What's interesting, this one terminates for [1..1000]:

```
minimalsolution d = take 1 [(x, y, d) | y <- [2..] :: [Int],
                            let x = round $ sqrt $ fromIntegral (d*y^2+1),
                            diophantine x y d]
```

Just added `:: [Int]`. Memory use looks stable at 1MB. Using Int64 reproduces the problem.

```
minimalsolution d = take 1 [(x, y, d) | y <- [2..] :: [Int64],
                            let x = round $ sqrt $ fromIntegral (d*y^2+1),
                            diophantine x y d]
```

---

Edit:

Well, as has been suggested, the difference is caused by overflow. The solution to d=61 is reported as (5983,20568,61), but 5983^2 is nowhere near 61*20568^2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any way to tell the compiler to change this behaviour and discard everything but the _current value of y_. It's basically a `while` loop. Is it not OK to use a list comprehension in this example?

Comment: @JohannesP It does seem weird that it wants to keep the list of trivial values instead of generating the values upon need. On the other hand, it seems it doesn't consider y a Int, so possibly attributes non-trivial cost. Declaring `y <- [2..] :: [Int]` solves the memory footprint problem for me (and terminates for d=[1..1000] within seconds)

Comment: Wow, that's a nice finding! I did not expect Haskell to behave this way. Are we encountering [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memory_leak#Holding_a_reference_for_a_too_long_time)? I played around a bit with `makeXs` as recommended there but wasn't able to get rid of the problem.

Comment: If you don't specify `y :: Int` then I guess it will default to `Integer`.  Presumably with an `Int` GHC is able to make more aggressive optimisations.

Comment: @TomEllis ok, but why does it not find x that satisfied diophantine? It would need to iterate y up to 20K times or so - surely footprint of that is not gigabytes?

Comment: Well d = 97 already has y = 6377352, and I can't even get a result for 61.  Are you sure the result is not astronomical?  I'm beginning to suspect `Int` only helps because it overflows ...

Comment: Also, are you sure your square roots are not introducing errors?

Comment: @TomEllis yes, I suspected overflow too, but didn't check :) a simple check tells us it is the case. (5983,20568,61) is not a solution to diophantine - 5983^2 is nowhere near 61*20568^2

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the comprehension creating unnecessary Double instances on each value of `y`.

I couldn't find a solution using list comprehensions that didn't have the space blowup. But rewriting using recursion yields a stable memory profile.

```
diophantine :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
diophantine x y d = x^2 - d*y^2 == 1

minimalsolution ::  Int -> (Int, Int, Int)
minimalsolution d = go 2
  where
    d0 = fromIntegral d
    go a =
      let y = fromIntegral a
          x = round $ sqrt $ (d0*y^2+1) in
      if diophantine x y d then
        (x, y, d)
      else
        go (y+1)
```

Comment: It's indeed much better with this! Btw: I had to insert a `fromIntegral` near `(d0*y^2+1)` to pacify my compiler. Now it's time to tweak the algorithm I guess.